# AutoCAD VBA - Creating a rectangle with a hatch pattern

Tags: vba, autocad

I am trying to create a rectangle using Excel data in VBA and then exporting the generated rectangle into AutoCAD. The code below sucessfully creates the rectangle in AutoCAD but keeps giving me "Invalid Object Array" for the hatchObj.AppendOuterLoop command. Does anyone have any idea why the hatch command isn't working:

```vb
Option Explicit
'OWS Plan View
Sub DrawRectangleHatch()
    Dim AutocadApp As Object
    Dim AutocadDoc As Object
    Dim RectArray(0 To 9) As Double
    Dim rectangle As Object
    Dim patternName As String
    Dim PatternType As Long
    Dim bAssociativity As Boolean
    Dim hatchObj As Object ' Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.AcadHatch
    Dim outerLoop() As Variant ' Use Variant data type for array of Autocad entities
    
    ' Define the hatch
    patternName = "ANSI31"
    PatternType = 0
    bAssociativity = True

    On Error Resume Next
    Set AutocadApp = GetObject(, "Autocad.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If AutocadApp Is Nothing Then
        Set AutocadApp = CreateObject("Autocad.Application")
        AutocadApp.Visible = True
    End If

    'Point1
    RectArray(0) = ActiveSheet.Range("B22")
    RectArray(1) = ActiveSheet.Range("C22")
    'Point2
    RectArray(2) = ActiveSheet.Range("B23")
    RectArray(3) = ActiveSheet.Range("C23")
    'Point3
    RectArray(4) = ActiveSheet.Range("B24")
    RectArray(5) = ActiveSheet.Range("C24")
    'Point4
    RectArray(6) = ActiveSheet.Range("B25")
    RectArray(7) = ActiveSheet.Range("C25")
    'Point1
    RectArray(8) = ActiveSheet.Range("B26")
    RectArray(9) = ActiveSheet.Range("C26")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set AutocadDoc = AutocadApp.ActiveDocument
    On Error GoTo 0

    If AutocadDoc Is Nothing Then
        Set AutocadDoc = AutocadApp.Documents.Add
    End If

    Set rectangle = AutocadDoc.modelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(RectArray)

    'hatch grid
    Set hatchObj = AutocadDoc.modelSpace.AddHatch(PatternType, patternName, bAssociativity)

   ' Use the correct array declaration for the outerLoop
    ReDim outerLoop(0)
    Set outerLoop(0) = AutocadDoc.modelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(RectArray)
    hatchObj.AppendOuterLoop (outerLoop)

    hatchObj.Evaluate

    AutocadApp.ZoomExtents

    Set rectangle = Nothing
    Set AutocadApp = Nothing
    Set AutocadDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this out?
You will probably have to adjust the hatch scale too. In my testing it was only a line visible but it was there without an error.

```
Sub DrawRectangleHatch()
    Dim AutocadApp As AcadApplication
    Dim AutocadDoc As AcadDocument
    Dim RectArray(0 To 9) As Double
    Dim rectangle As AcadLWPolyline
    Dim patternName As String
    Dim PatternType As Long
    Dim bAssociativity As Boolean
    Dim hatchObj As AcadHatch ' Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.AcadHatch
    Dim OuterLoop(0 To 0) As AcadLWPolyline
    
    ' Define the hatch
    patternName = "ANSI31"
    PatternType = 0
    bAssociativity = True

    On Error Resume Next
    Set AutocadApp = GetObject(, "Autocad.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If AutocadApp Is Nothing Then
        Set AutocadApp = CreateObject("Autocad.Application")
        AutocadApp.Visible = True
    End If

    'Point1
    RectArray(0) = ActiveSheet.Range("B22")
    RectArray(1) = ActiveSheet.Range("C22")
    'Point2
    RectArray(2) = ActiveSheet.Range("B23")
    RectArray(3) = ActiveSheet.Range("C23")
    'Point3
    RectArray(4) = ActiveSheet.Range("B24")
    RectArray(5) = ActiveSheet.Range("C24")
    'Point4
    RectArray(6) = ActiveSheet.Range("B25")
    RectArray(7) = ActiveSheet.Range("C25")
    'Point1
    RectArray(8) = ActiveSheet.Range("B26")
    RectArray(9) = ActiveSheet.Range("C26")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set AutocadDoc = AutocadApp.ActiveDocument
    On Error GoTo 0

    If AutocadDoc Is Nothing Then
        Set AutocadDoc = AutocadApp.Documents.Add
    End If

    Set rectangle = AutocadDoc.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(RectArray)

    'hatch grid
    Set hatchObj = AutocadDoc.ModelSpace.AddHatch(PatternType, patternName, bAssociativity)

   ' Use the correct array declaration for the outerLoop
    Set OuterLoop(0) = AutocadDoc.ModelSpace.AddLightWeightPolyline(RectArray)
    hatchObj.AppendOuterLoop (OuterLoop)

    hatchObj.Evaluate

    AutocadApp.ZoomExtents

    Set rectangle = Nothing
    Set AutocadApp = Nothing
    Set AutocadDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```